# Como sumar campo Time de SQL Server

Tags: sql

estoy trabajando en un sistema para una radiodifusora, este lleva la cuenta de los archivos de audio reproducidos en el día, así como también la duración de cada archivo de audio. Esta información la guardo en una tabla que tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El campo Descripcion contiene el nombre del archivo de audio reproducido, este dato puede repetirse pues durante el dia se puede repetir una determinada canción o audio varias veces.

Ahora necesito agrupar por Descripcion, obtener la cantidad de veces que se reprodujo un audio, así como también el total de minutos o segundos que se reprodujo ya sea en un valor entero o en un mismo tipo de dato Time. La consulta que tengo armada hasta ahora va así

```
SELECT        
OpeRadioReporte.Descripcion,
Count(*) as TotalReproducciones,
SUM(OpeRadioReporte.Duracion) -- ESTO ME GENERA ERROR PUES NO ME SUMA EL CAMPO TIME.
FROM            
OpeRadioReporte
WHERE
MONTH(OpeRadioReporte.Fecha) = 9
AND
YEAR(OpeRadioReporte.Fecha) = 2018
GROUP BY
OpeRadioReporte.Descripcion
```

Donde al intentar sumar el campo Duracion de tipo Time me genera un error.

Comment: Podrias el tipo de dato a int (duracion en segundos)
y luego en el select obtienes la duracion en horas minutos y segundos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sumar una columna `TIME` debes convertir la misma a un valor numérico, como imagino que el nivel de precisión de tu requerimiento son los segundos hay que llevar el `TIME` a segundos. Una forma es descomponer el dato en horas, minutos y segundos con `DATEPART()` y multiplicar cada parte por la cantidad de segundos. Otra forma interesante es convertir el `TIME` a un `DATETIME` y obtener la diferencia con un `0 AS DATETIME`.

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE (
    Duracion    TIME
)

-- Son dos Registros que suman justo 4 horas    
INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (Duracion) VALUES ('01:12:15'), ('02:47:45')

SELECT  SUM(
        DATEPART(SECOND, [Duracion]) + 
                60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, [Duracion]) + 
                3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, [Duracion] ) 
        ),
    SUM(
        DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,cast(Duracion AS DATETIME))
    )
    FROM @Ejemplo


-- Resultado en segundos
14400
```

El resultado final serán segundos, si quieres visualizarlos nuevamente como un `TIME` puedes convertirlos de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, 14400, 0) AS TIME)
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba!. Gracias amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tengo una consulta que puede ayudarte un poco a hacer algo similar, no se si te sirva. Tu necesitas sumar minutos, por lo menos tengo eso, ya que con segundos es algo complicado.

```
SELECT
     [Descripcion],
     SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Duracion], 108),':',''), 3,2))) as [Entero] 
FROM OpeRadioReporte  group by Descripcion
```

Espero que puedas hacer pruebas y me comentes

Saludos